# What is the expected time to converge to a steady state where each user has a unique rank?

Tags: probability

I am a new user here. I have a question please but I am not sure of the response:   Supposing that we have three users and each of them has a random rank of the set $\{1,2,3\}$. Let us start the game, at each time slot when two or more users select the same rank, then a collision occurs, and the colliding  users should regenerate their rank. Assuming that $p$ is the probability of no collision. After a finite number of collisions, each user will have a unique rank that is called the steady state. Then, what is the expected time to converge to a steady state where each user has a unique rank?
In fact, I have two answers:  $E(t)=   ∑ t*(1 − p)^t\,p\;$   or   $\;E(t)= ∑ t*(1 − p)^{t-1}\,p$.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! You can edit your post to update it (I've just changed it to add the missing $p$ factor)

Comment: Two answers is too much! And frankly speaking I do not understand these answers. Correct answer should be just a number, not a function of (t). Someting like "the answer is 20" (this is just an example, correct answer is probably a smaller number). Which would mean that if many groups use the described approach to establish the ranks, some groups would need more than 20 steps, others - less than 20 steps, but the average number of step required is 20. And what is "p"? Probability that there are no collisions on the next step depend on the ranks on current step, so it's not some fixed number.

Comment: thanks for your replay, however my answers based on the relation between the probability and the expected relation  E(t)=∑t∗Pt, where Pt is the probability of no collision at the instant t. I am not sure if the correct answer, as you said, should be a number but does not depend on (t). but after a finite number of slots, the summation of E(t) will go to zero   because of (1-p)<1.

Comment: In addition, my above answers based on the idea that at the instant t=5 for example P5= (1-p)*(1-p)*(1-p)*(1-p)*p : P5 represents a no collision at instant 5 then i suppose that we have collision at instant 1,2,3 and 4. While at the instant 5 no collision in this case we obtain  E(t)=∑t∗(1−p)^(t−1)*p .

Comment: I understand your clarifications, thanks! In your calculations you use $p$ - probability of event that if there is a collision on some step there will be no collisions on next step. But are you sure if $p$ depends on whether all three users have to regenerate ranks or only two of them? (Or may be only one? :) ) May be $p$ is different fot these cases and thus may be $p$ on step 1 is different than $p$ on step 2? Can you calculate $p$ for the very first step when all three users generate their ranks for the very first time?

Comment: In fact, the general definition of p is  the probability where each user orthogonalizes to a unique rank, then this probability depends of all the users